# smarty, include tpl file

Tags: php, smarty

how include file with smarty?
i use this function:
{include file="modules/news.tpl"}

but show error:

Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "modules/news.tpl"

File exist and is in modules/news.tpl directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
{include file="modules/news.tpl"}
```

to

```
{include file="./modules/news.tpl"}
```

This will at least determine the current location you're at.

Comment: Yeah! That is it, thank you for the solution... Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

While I'm not 100% sure here, I believe that Smarty resolves your includes by looking in the `template_dir` config variable.

See the doc: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.template.dir.tpl and http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl .

Answer (score 2):

Smarty requires absolute paths unfortunately. We normally set a $docroot enviroiment variable in PHP and parse it to the templates so we can use it:

{include file="$docroot/modules/news.tpl"}

I understand this is a one repeated request to smarty to be able to include templates on the same path as the current one.

Comment: This is not true. Paths are relative to whatever you passed to setTemplateDir().

Answer (score 0):

you have to include this file in php (action) files and then it will works in tpl as well.

Thanks.